# page is still reloading with event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery

if the select drop-down menu has value of NULL, it should stop the page from loading. The jQuery works alerting the user of the issue, however the page still continues to the next page. Any assistance would  be superb. Thanks

Luke

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="question-1">1. What age group are you?</label> <br>
  <select class="drop-down" id = "ageChoice">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="16minus">16 or below</option>
    <option value="16-18">16 to 18</option>
    <option value="19-25">19 to 25</option>
    <option value="26-34">26 to 34</option>
    <option value="35-42">35 to 42</option>
    <option value="43-50">43 to 50</option>
    <option value="51-60">51 to 60</option>
    <option value="61plus">61+</option>
  </select>  
</fieldset>

  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id= "next" value="Next" onClick="location.href='first-test.html' ">

$("#next").click(function () {

    var age = $('#ageChoice');

    if (age.val() === '') {
         event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please select your age group, thank you.");

    }
    else 
        return;
});
```

Comment: Check your console, there should be an error about `event` being undefined. Add it as an argument for the callback function.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, Apologies i'm new to jQuery, do you mean the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/uvyqtsxn/
if so this didn't seem to work. Thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so because you have two click handlers, the event is being processed twice. The 'Default' you are trying to prevent is not the onClick="location.href='first-test.html' . That is being processed after your jQuery click function. So we take the onClick out of the html. and add the functionality to the jQuery click event (we could do it either way, but becuase you already have most of the code set up already we'll do it this way)

Here is the reworked code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="question-1">1. What age group are you?</label> <br>
   <select class="drop-down" id = "ageChoice">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="16minus">16 or below</option>
    <option value="16-18">16 to 18</option>
    <option value="19-25">19 to 25</option>
    <option value="26-34">26 to 34</option>
    <option value="35-42">35 to 42</option>
    <option value="43-50">43 to 50</option>
    <option value="51-60">51 to 60</option>
    <option value="61plus">61+</option>
  </select>  
</fieldset>

  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id= "next" value="Next">
```

and the jquery:

```
$("#next").on('click', function (event) {

    var age = $('#ageChoice');

    if (age.val() === '') {
      alert("Please select your age group, thank you.");
    } else {
      location.href='first-test.html'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it works! Been at it for hours. I gather it's a more efficient way of writing code removing the href out of the html and placing it in the jQuery?

Comment: Well, it all depends on what you are trying to do, 'onclick=...' and $().on('click',func) are essentially doing the same exact thing. Just avoid having two separate watchers watching for the same event.